# Counting the number of elements with different values of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line chart starting from this dataset:
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZeDQ.png)

where every line points out the number of the smell detected (so in my case 18 for version `1.4.1`; 20 for version `1.5.1` and so on) and on the x axis I want to put every version that I've under exam.

The problem is that I don't know how to make a count for each version in R, so I can pass that counter (column) as a parameter for the `ggplot2` function.

EDIT: sorry for the misunderstanding and for the bad english..Andrew gave me the right hint; i got a new problem now: creating a plot from that frequency table give me a single dot corresponding to the frequency of the version, but if possible i want to outline that with a line, more similar to a line chart. This is what i've obtained so far: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHsBI.png)

Comment: Post your data (or a subset of your data) using `dput` rather than an image, so that we can use it to answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps something like `as.data.frame(table(df$version))` will give you what you need

Answer (score 1):

Since you will have only 1 value per version - the count - a line chart is not the best fit. The easiest way to plot the count is a histogram. using ggplot, the following code will plot the count of each version:

```
ggplot(dataset) + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = version), stat = "count")
```

For a sample dataset, the reasult will be the following:

```
dataset <- data.frame(version = c(rep("1.4.1", 18), rep("1.5.1", 20)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your dataset or the description you gave. Therefore I only answer the problem posted in the headline. You can use the function `unique()` to get a vector of all the unique values of a vector (so duplicates are removed). And you can ascertain the length of that new vector using the function `length()`.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)
length(unique(x))
```

Gives you the number of different elements of the vector x, which is 5 in this case.

Good luck!